# Mocking collections with Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

So this is something I guess many people want to do, mock a collection.  In the past with Rhino I have done this with something like:

```
var col_mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomCollection>(); // returns ICustom let's say
List<ICustom> col_real = new List<ICustom>();
col_real.Add(custom_mock1);
col_real.Add(custom_mock2);
col_real.Add(custom_mock3);
col_mock.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(col_real.GetEnumerator());
```

So yup this works fine, when you foreach col_mock you get the mocked (custom_mock1 etc.) objects back. Great! We have successfully mocked a custom collection by using a typed list to actually store a load of mocked objects.

The problem is, you can only do this once! you can only foreach this collection once.  Does anyone know (without creating an actual custom collection...) how I can achieve the mocking of a custom collection which can be iterated more than once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the enumerator is only instantiated once, when you call `Return`. Then it returns the same instance which is already at the end of the list after the first `foreach`.

You need to instantiate a new enumerator each time when `GetEnumerator` is called. You could use `WhenCalled` to do so.

`Return` is still needed, because Rhino Mocks will complain when it is missing. But it doesn't matter what you pass as argument.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetEnumerator()
{
    IList<int> col_mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IList<int>>();
    List<int> col_real = new List<int>();
    col_real.Add(1);
    col_real.Add(2);
    col_real.Add(3);
    col_mock
        .Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator())
        // create new enumerator instance for each call
        .WhenCalled(call => call.ReturnValue = col_real.GetEnumerator())
        .Return(null) // is ignored, but needed for Rhinos validation
        .Repeat.Any();

    foreach (int i in col_mock)
    {
    }

    int count = 0;
    foreach (int i in col_mock)
    {
        count++;
    }
    Assert.AreSame(3, count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! and well done, actually the Return(null) and Repeat.Any calls don't seem to  be required.  I hadn't used the WhenCalled before, this is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 4):

> So this is something I guess many people want to do, mock a collection.

Actually, no. The point of a mock is to quickly conjure up an object with a specific interface and behavior that you have full control over, so that you can exercise your class under test.

But in the case where you need an `ICollection<Foo>`, you can typically just create a `List<Foo>` instance. You can populate a list in your unit test any way you want; you already have full control.

Or suppose you need a `IEnumerable<Foo>` with more interesting behavior that you can't produce with a list, like an infinite enumerable or an enumerable that throws exceptions.  This can be done by defining an iterator method in your unit test class with the `yield` keyword. Again, a mock is not necessary.

Comment: I have to disagree with you here.  When your collection is not an ICollection<T> (or derivations of like IList<T> etc) but actually an oldschool custom collection object which you cannot change but must use (as in my case); then you will need to mock the collection object itself.  

Some of the interfaces I am using have not been refactored since .Net 1.1.  

Thanks for the input though.